# How to call getSharedPreferences from updateBaseContextLocale

Tags: java, android

I need to access SharedPreferences on updateBaseContextLocale, which is running before onCreate. When I call SharedPreferences from updateBaseContextLocale, I get this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
```

If I call getSharedPreferences from onCreate, it is too late to change the locale. Here is the code that I need to run:

```
    private Context updateBaseContextLocale(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("Settings", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String language = prefs.getString("Language", "en");
        Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            return updateResourcesLocale(context, locale);
        }
        return updateResourcesLocaleLegacy(context, locale);
    }
```

Comment: use the context

Comment: Thank you very much for fast and correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of just:
`SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("Settings", MODE_PRIVATE);`

Use the context received in the method parameter to get SharedPrefs:

`SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("Settings", MODE_PRIVATE);`

Comment: You're welcome, I just noticed @Rajnish has also commented on your question, with the same answer that I have. You should give him an upvote, just for help.

Comment: I think I can't upvote because of my low reputation level. But I thanked him too as comment for his fast and helpful reply.